# laravel Auth - redirection after login with additonal data

Tags: authentication, laravel-5

I'm considering how to make redirection after login with additional collections of data. I can do it with one collection:

```
///trait AuthenticatesUsers in Auth/LoginController


protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    $request->session()->regenerate();

    $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);
    $products = Product::all();
    return $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())
        ? : redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath())->with('pr', $products);
}
```

How can I do it with more than one collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can chain the `with` method as many times as you like:

```
///trait AuthenticatesUsers in Auth/LoginController


protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    $request->session()->regenerate();

    $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);
    $products = Product::all();
    $foo = Foo::all();
    $bar = Bar::all();
    return $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())
        ? : redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath())
                ->with('pr', $products)
                ->with('foo', $foo)
                ->with('bar', $bar);
}
```